# How i can render piece of a website with PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

How i can render piece of a website with PhantomJS :(For example)

```
var page=require('webpage').create();
var ur ='http://www.sd.gov/';
function kk(){page.open(ur, function (status) {
       this.s = function(){
        var p = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementById('exampleHeader1').style.getPropertyValue("background-image").replace(/^(url)\(|\)/g,'');  
          });
        return p;
        }
        return s();
    phantom.exit();   
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phantomjs allows you to render a web page to a file using [WebPage.Render](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html). This will render the whole page or the rect specified by [webpage.clipRect](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/clip-rect.html)
To render a piece of a website (an HTMl element), you could use [element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect): This will give give the bounding box of the HTML element.

A possible script is

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1600, height: 1200 };

var getElementBounds = function (elementId) {
    return page.evaluate(function (id) {
        var clipRect = document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            top: clipRect.top,
            left: clipRect.left,
            width: clipRect.width,
            height: clipRect.height
        };
    }, elementId);
}

var url = 'http://www.sd.gov/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var clipRect = getElementBounds('exampleHeader1');
        page.clipRect = clipRect;
        page.render('header.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 1000);
});
```